# ASP.Net: 301 Redirects

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have the bellow code to redirect but it does not seem to work well

```
<configuration>
    <location path="article.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newsite.co.uk/new-page-a/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

    <location path="old-page-2.html">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newsite.co.uk/new-page-b/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" destination="http://www.newsite.co.uk/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any help

Comment: If possible, give up this approach and write a few URL rewrite rules instead. That would be cleaner to maintain and extend.

Comment: @LexLi The site is already live and has been indexed by google, hence doing the rules this way is to ensure that google understands we are not having duplicate content but have moved codebase

Comment: URL rewriting provides equivalent functionality, but generally speaking simpler to configure (depends on your familiarity on regular expressions and so on). Try it out first, and you will see your current configuration (relying on location tag) is not flexible enough.